# How to prevent divs from wrapping while hiding overflow?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a row containing several divs. I'm trying to prevent the contained divs from wrapping. I also do not want a scrollbar. I've tried overflow hidden and set a width on the row.

EDIT: Constraints dictate that this must be done without tables, javascript, or external libraries.

Is there a way to do this with css without resorting to tables?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ozsumdfb/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:3px;
    background-color: #6C6;
}
.row {
    width:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I'm trying to prevent the contained divs from wrapping. ` you dont want them to go to the next row?

Comment: Questions like this one appear every once in a while. Google for scripts like: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html and http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: That is correct jmore009. I do not want them to wrap.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I'm trying to avoid javascript and libraries as well. I would like to do this purely with css.

Comment: @PrimalWyld do you know how many divs you will have? will it only be 6? or will it change dynamically?

Comment: @PrimalWyld why you think those people build such JS libraries? Logically not cause it can be done in CSS only.

Comment: @jmore009, there will be a dynamic number of divs contained within the row. I need the row to be able to be resized on demand and only show the squares that are required.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I'm not going to argue with you about the reasons for external libraries. My requirements demand that this be done only with html and css.

Can you provide an answer that fits within these constraints?

Comment: @PrimalWyld but at some point you need to wrap them, no? otherwise you would get horizontal scroll bars

Comment: @jmoore009, the goal is to never wrap them, if anything I want them to cut off the content where I choose. To give you a greater understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish, take a look at this more complex example but using the same concept. http://jsfiddle.net/g1tm037s/1/
I want to be able to constrain the hex-rows and cut the hex off on the right hand side like it is doing on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insteed of `float:left` you could try `display:inline-block` then just add:

> .row {white-space:nowrap;  }

is this what you are looking for?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozsumdfb/3/)

Comment: Your example solves the problem for the squares. I'm going to mark it as the answer. It seems I need to ask another question for the hexes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I added a `wrapper` after `row` had them both with 618px since you had 6 squares padding left 3px (that is (100 + 3)*6 = 618). Hope this helps.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
    <div class="square">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.square {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:3px;
    background-color: #6C6;
}
.row { 
    width:618px; 
    overflow-x:auto; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.wrapper { 
    width: 618px; 
}
```

Comment: When you constrain the row it still scrolls or wraps.